# iOS 9: UICollectionView DataSource is not set

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios9

Since **iOS 9** launched, Crashalytics has reported a fair number of crashes from `NSInternalInconsistencyException:`UICollectionView`data source is not set` even when the data source is set. It feels like it might be an SDK bug, but I have no idea how to avoid it.

Details:

- This only happens on iOS 9. Hundreds of occurrences on iOS 9, zero on 7/8
- This happens on the main thread, deep in `UIKit` code
- I am setting the `DataSource`, but it looks like the `UICollectionView` is outliving the `DataSource`?
- No consistent repro, but it happens many times a day according to `Crashalytics`.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x181a91900 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1810fff80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181a917d0 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x18240499c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x1869152dc -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
5  UIKit                          0x1867e8990 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
6  UIKit                          0x1867e389c -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
```

Comment: *"it looks like the UICollectionView is outliving the datasource"*… this is entirely possible if you are not ensuring the data source is retained. The collection view will not retain it for you.

Comment: @AaronBrager I should have mentioned: the datasource is the ViewController, which is the only thing retaining the collection view.

Comment: Is it possible you're later un-setting the data source? Or that your view controller is being deallocated?

Comment: have no problem with it. I think your dataSource is not valid, you should try reproduce

Comment: @Wingzero what do you mean not valid? It works fine. It's possible my app is just higher traffic, so I see more occurrences of a rare bug (it only happens once every 50k sessions or so).

Comment: @AaronBrager just triple checked. Definitely not unsetting it anywhere. The only time I touch it is `.datasource = self` in the init function.

Comment: you still have the issue for over 3 months? I don't see this happens on my side at all, for iOS 9. Anyway, you should google "UICollectionView dataSource is not set" then

Comment: @Wingzero thanks for the tip, I never would have thought of that!

Comment: @delrox we're seeing the same thing on ios9. It's very hard to reproduce, it happens when the view is animated off the navigation controller stack via the 'back' button.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am getting the same error, but only when I test on my iPad mini which has iOS 9.3.5.  I don't get this error on any iPhones, but that could be because they all run iOS 10+.

Comment: I got this error when I set footerHeight in ios9