# NSInternalInconsistencyException with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Recently, I have been assigned to deal with crash reports and I found that there are a lot of crash report that come from 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' that are originated from 'UICollectionView'. The 2 reasons that were common are

- `'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView dataSource is not set'`
- `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of items in section 0 when there are only 0 sections in the collection view'`

I was not able to reproduce the crash. I'm sorry that I am not able to post the code or the full crash report, but I will try my best to briefly explain the situation.

I have a `UIViewController` that is holding a `UICollectionView`. The `UIViewController` acts as the `dataSource` and `delegate` for the `UICollectionView`. And the `dataSource` and `delegate` are assigned in the storyboard.

First, I thought that somehow the `dataSource` disappear somewhere, which would have cause the crash. So I tried to force the crash by setting `dataSource = nil`, but as expected it did not crash. I also found a solution here which says to check if `dataSource` in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` is equal to nil or deal with it accordingly. I tried to force `dataSource = nil` in there, but still can't reproduce the problem (
[UICollectionView and Supplementary View crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777059/uicollectionview-and-supplementary-view-crash))

Is it possible that somehow the `UIViewController` that acts as a `dataSource` for the `UICollectionView` died somehow so `UICollectionView` does not have the dataSource? But wouldn't this be the same as `UICollectionView.dataSource = nil`, which would not crash the app anyway?

Would it help if I separate `UIViewController` and  `UICollectionViewDataSource` and then assign the `dataSource` in the `viewDidLoad`?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction in solving this problem.

Thanks

Edited: found a similar problem here [iOS 9: UICollectionView dataSource is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074706/ios-9-uicollectionview-datasource-is-not-set) However, there is no solution yet.

Comment: show your code brother

Comment: Hey, I would love to post my code. However, I'm not sure if my company would allow me to.